# 16.04 runs smooth from usb, EXTREMELEY laggy/choppy once installed...help!

Tags: usb

Trying to think of info you guys might care about...

- installed alongside windows 7, partition created in windows 7 disk management
- downloaded updates and proprietary stuff, whatever the two checkboxes are during install
- specs: MOBO - Gigabyte H170N || STORAGE - Samsung 850 EVO || CPU - i5-6600 || GPU - MSI 1070 Gaming X
- the slowness starts all the way in grub, affecting the login screen as well
- affects everything, typing, clicking, movnig windows around, there's a several second delay after everything -- except the mouse, which has a clear input delay but only of a few hundred milisconds and it draws on the display about 24 frames per second instead of 1 frame per second like the rest of the UI seems.

Mouse and keyboard work, wifi works, it can access windows folders, if something isn't working I haven't noticed. But if I click on anything it takes a second or two to respond, and you see it get drawn on the screen from top to bottom. If an item is closed from the bar on the left, the animation is SUPER choppy, like watching 5 frames over the course of 1 to 2 seconds.

I feel like this is a simple fix, like a driver problem or something obvious. Any ideas?

EDIT: OMG it's fixed.  I feel like this could happen to anyone so here's what I did. Went into System Settings > Details > Install Updates. Took a minute or two doing some things, then asked me to restart. It's been blazing fast (as it should be on this high end system) since reboot, and I suppose it will last. Good luck out there noobs.

Comment: Not a simple fix, unfortunately. You may try to install the latest Nvidia driver but even that may not perform as it should.  GTX1070 is very new and not quite supported in Linux yet.

Comment: @CelticWarrior There is support for GTX 1070 since the launch day on the proprietary drivers. Although, if you are talking about nouveau, there'll probably be no proper support for some time due to signed image requirement.

Comment: I said "You may try to install the latest Nvidia driver but even that may not perform as it should". The Ubuntu forums have many threads about problem with GTX 1070 even with the latest Nvidia drivers. I'm sure the situation will improve but we're not there yet.